# Can not change actions-on-google project from dialogflow fulfillment to smarthome fulfillment

Tags: actions-on-google

I create dialogflow agent (with exited cloud project) and it automatic create action on google .
Now i want to use action on google with smarthome fulfillment but i can not change action on google  project or delete it ( is say must delete all my cloud project)

pleaze help me how to change to use smarthome fulfillment without delete my cloud project (i currently use firebase message, google map api)

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need to create a new project. In the onboarding page, make sure you select the Smart Home option.

The nice thing is that you won't necessarily have to recreate all your original project code, as in the Actions console you can just point to your endpoints even if hosted on another project.

[image: https://developers.google.com/actions/images/smarthome-card.png]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/actions/images/smarthome-card.png))</sub>

Comment: thank for help, i contacted with support and receiver same answer,  thank u